# how can i use getfilter method in fragment class without create adapter class . when user is searching their name also find the location of map

Tags: android

I want to search the name on the list on searchview widget then also display the location of user on map  i want to use method getfilter in fragment only not adpter class.

here my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <!-- <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                 android:id="@+id/mapview"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="@color/find_location_linear_bg_color"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                    android:text="CLUB NAME" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                    android:text="TYPE" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                    android:text="DISTANCE" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lvFitMixDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

also I add my fragment class

```
package fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.practical.omnipresent.fitmix.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import adapter.CustomFindLocationListAdapter;
import model.CustomFindLocationListModel;

/**
 * Created by omnipresent on 3/16/16.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class FinderFitMixLocationFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,Filterable {
    ListView lvFitMixDescription;

    private SearchView searchView;
    ArrayList<CustomFindLocationListModel> item;
    public ArrayList<CustomFindLocationListModel> orig;

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private static View rootView;

    MapView mapView;

    CustomFindLocationListAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<LatLng> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<CustomFindLocationListModel>> hasMapData;

    //    double latitude = 17.385044;     
    //    double longitude = 78.486671;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (rootView != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(rootView);
        }
        try {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.find_location_fragment, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
            Log.e("ERror", e.getMessage());
        }
        try {

            //initilizeMap(17.385044, 78.486671);

            item = new ArrayList<>();
            CustomFindLocationListModel model;
            String name[] = {"ram", "raj", "kan", "manu", "tanu", "bhanu"};
            String type[] = {"ram11", "raj11", "kan11", "manu11", "tanu11", "bhanu11"};
            String distance[] = {"1213", "1213", "1213", "1213", "1213", "1213"};
            String lat[]={"51.5145160","51.5289160","51.5198260","51.5105120","51.5143140","51.5655260"};
            String longt[]={"-0.1350080","-0.1291040","-0.1300050","-0.1780080","-0.1690040","-0.1270060"};

            //   item.clear();

            lvFitMixDescription = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvFitMixDescription);
            searchView = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchView);


            hasMapData=new HashMap<>();
            String key;
            for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                model = new CustomFindLocationListModel();
                model.setClubName(name[i]);
                key=name[i];
                model.setType(type[i]);
                model.setDistance(distance[i]);
                model.setLat(Double.valueOf(lat[i]));
                model.setLng(Double.valueOf(longt[i]));

                item.add(model);
                hasMapData.put(key,item);
            }


            adapter = new CustomFindLocationListAdapter(getActivity(), item);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //here change
            lvFitMixDescription.setAdapter(adapter);
            lvFitMixDescription.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            GoogleMap_View();

            lvFitMixDescription.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                }
            });


            Setup_Search_View();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Address Map", "Could not initialize google play", e);
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    private void Setup_Search_View() {
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
            lvFitMixDescription.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            lvFitMixDescription.setFilterText(query);

            //  cs=query;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            lvFitMixDescription.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            lvFitMixDescription.setFilterText(newText);
            // cs=newText;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return true;
    }


    private void GoogleMap_View() {

        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (googleMap == null) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
           hasMapData.get("key");
            LatLngBounds.Builder bld = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

            for(int i=0;i<hasMapData.size();i++)
            {
                CustomFindLocationListModel model;


                model=item.get(i);

                LatLng ll = new LatLng(model.getLat(), model.getLng());
                bld.include(ll);

                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(model.getLat(), model.getLng())).title("Haidrabad");
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(model.getLat(), model.getLng())).zoom(8).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<CustomFindLocationListModel> results = new ArrayList<>();
                if (orig == null)
                    orig = item;
                if (constraint != null) {
                    if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                        for (final CustomFindLocationListModel g : orig) {
                            if (g.getClubName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))
                                results.add(g);

                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                item = (ArrayList<CustomFindLocationListModel>) results.values;
                // map_list=(ArrayList<LatLngModel>)results.values;

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}

Adpter class 
package adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.practical.omnipresent.fitmix.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import model.CustomFindLocationListModel;

/**
 * Created by omnipresent on 3/16/16.
 */
public class CustomFindLocationListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<CustomFindLocationListModel> item;
    public ArrayList<CustomFindLocationListModel> orig;
    //public ArrayList<LatLngModel> map_list;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomFindLocationListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomFindLocationListModel> item) {
        this.context = context;
        this.item = item;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return item.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder viewHolder=new Holder();
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_find_location_row,null);
        viewHolder.txtClubName= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtClubName);
        viewHolder.txtType=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtType);
        viewHolder.txtDistance=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDistance);


        CustomFindLocationListModel model=item.get(position);

        viewHolder.txtClubName.setText(model.getClubName());
        viewHolder.txtType.setText(model.getType());
        viewHolder.txtDistance.setText(model.getDistance());

        return convertView;
    }

    public  class Holder
    {
        TextView txtClubName,txtType,txtDistance;
         GoogleMap googleMap;
    }
}
item or model class
public class CustomFindLocationListModel  {
    double lat,lng;
    String clubName,type,distance;

    public String getClubName() {
        return clubName;
    }

    public void setClubName(String clubName) {
        this.clubName = clubName;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    //google map lat long

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a huge amount of code to wade through, try being a little more specific about where the problem is

Comment: i think getfilterable method is not working in fragment class to on searchview on  textchange method